# Anylogic: how to end wait block on schedule, not on timeout

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, simulation, anylogic

I want a boat to leave the port every 120 minutes, from the start of my model.

The boat arrives on an exponential distribution, it enters in a restricted area (the port) and enters in a wait block in order to embark all the passengers. I tried to use "Enable exit on timeout", but the timeout starts when the boat enters the wait block and I want the boat to respect the scheduled intervals.
(I don't care about hour or day, but only about fixed intervals)

I used a schedule block, I removed "Enable exit on timeout" on wait block, but I cannot establish a connection between Schedule and Wait block: for the moment the boat remains at the port and doesn't leave.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the "exit on timeout". Boats will now be in the Wait block forever, unless you free them explicitly.

Use the Schedule action code to call `myWaitBlock.free(agent)` where agent is the boat you want to leave.

If you only have 1 boat in the wait block, it can be `myWaitBlock.free(myWaitBlock.get(0))`, else loop across all agents inside it to free whichever boat you want.